# Ivy disable completion for a command in minibuffer

Tags: files, completion, ivy

Can I disable ivy completion for a single command while in minibuffer?

For example I am in folder ~/code/study/ . If I open find file and autocomplete with Ivy I will see

```
Find file: ~/code/study/

./ 
../ 
[...]
```

and I want, in a single jump go to ~/other/code/study. Since I have ivy-mode to autocomplete I cannot move my cursor to the first / and just type other there. This is being a pain for some things. Can I somehow edit the first part of a completion or even disable completion temporarily just for this command?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 31):

I think what you're looking for is `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`) in the mini buffer. This function is described as follows in the [Ivy manual](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer):

> Exits with the current input instead of the current candidate (like
>   other commands).
>
> This is useful e.g. when you call find-file to create a new file, but
>   the desired name matches an existing file. In that case, using `C-j`
>   would select that existing file, which isn't what you want—use this
>   command instead.

Comment: But how can I get my cursor to ~/<here>/code/study to edit and apply the immediate-done?

Comment: I don't think you can with `C-M-j`, but it is one way of disabling completion.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple approaches to file navigation that apply here.

Just to rephrase your statement:

> switch from ~/code/study to ~/other/code/study

1. Easiest and most consistent: use <kbd>~</kbd> to switch to `~/` and navigate from there.
2. Assume you visited `~/code/study` once before in the current Emacs session. Press <kbd>C-r</kbd> to access all files you visited before. You can erase the file part with <kbd>C-k</kbd>.
3. Assume you have `~/code/study` as a bookmark or in `recentf`. Press <kbd>M-o b</kbd> to get completion for those.
4. Assume you are in the `dired` buffer of `~/code/study`. Press <kbd>0w</kbd> to copy the current path. Press <kbd>C-x C-f C-y</kbd>: you can edit the yank in the minibuffer.

### Edit: one more approach

With the most recent [commit](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/commit/3fc42cd4e89066fabe7a4bc35a48fb73d8005b34), you can press <kbd>C-M-o w C-y</kbd> to edit the full path in the minibuffer.
If you use this a lot, `counsel-find-file-map` is available to bind this combination to something shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the filename root during completion by typing `DEL` or `<backspace>`. Each such keypress switches to the parent directory.

See section [File Name Completion](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#file-name-completion) of the Ivy User Manual for more information. In particular, you may be interested in the the special handling of slashes and tildes - entering two slashes during any part of the completion will change the directory to the root directory (`/`) and similarly a tilde will switch to your home directory.

See also customisable variable [`ivy-on-del-error-function`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#defcustoms).

Comment: If I do that I'd have "~/code/study" then backspace "~/code/" then "~" code. And I'd had to start again with Dropbox/code/study. I'd like to avoid that repeat of code/study.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022-02-19, the [File Name Completion](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#file-name-completion) section of the Ivy manual, that [@Basil mentioned](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32873/15483) earlier, now includes <kbd>C-M-y</kbd> bound by default to [ivy-insert-current-full](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#:%7E:text=ivy%2Dinsert%2Dcurrent%2Dfull).  That keybinding allows you to directly edit that path, without requiring further Ivy/Counsel customization.

### Example:

Open up a directory, say `/tmp/dir1` and notice that the `/tmp/dir1` text is not truly editable (see [Rafa de Castro's comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32862/ivy-disable-completion-for-a-command-in-minibuffer#comment50818_32873) caution about <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> deleting parent directory text that is the very text that is desired to be edited):

[image: noticing the non-editable text]

Typing <kbd>C-M-y</kbd> pastes the `/tmp/dir1` path into the editable text area of the minibuffer:

[image: after typing C-M-y]

Your arrow key bindings are now active as normal and you can edit it:

[image: edited text area]

### Update 2022-09-15 08:59:22 for clearing initial input before insertion in <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>

An annoyance, slightly related to [Mike Crowes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/20409/mike-crowe) [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63010/how-can-i-edit-the-beginning-of-the-counsel-find-file-filename-whilst-preserving#comment99526_63010) on [his question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63010/how-can-i-edit-the-beginning-of-the-counsel-find-file-filename-whilst-preserving), is when you have typed in some input characters *before* typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>, the directory path is *appended* to that path, instead of overwriting it with that new directory path. This is annoying in the majority of cases whereby the users intent is to edit that directory path somewhere in the middle of that long path, type <kbd>RETURN</kbd>, only to be baffled as to why Emacs shows some non-existent path with that initial input in front of the path.

Below is my workaround for that annoyance using `advice-add` (advice):

[enter link description here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63010/how-can-i-edit-the-beginning-of-the-counsel-find-file-filename-whilst-preserving#comment99526_63010)

```el
  (defun bg-ivy-insert-current-full-clear-input-before-insert ()
    "Clear the input before calling `ivy-insert-current-full'."
    ;; Use (line-beginning-position) instead of (point-min) because of text properties in use that inhibit motion:
    (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (point-max)))

  (advice-add 'ivy-insert-current-full :before #'bg-ivy-insert-current-full-clear-input-before-insert)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still get the default find-file behavior if you do

```
(defun default-find-file ()
  (interactive)
  (exit-minibuffer)
   (let  ((completing-read-function 'completing-read-default))
     (call-interactively 'find-file) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the complete path (again) then edit:

```
C-M-y (ivy-insert-current-full)
```

Now the minibuffer looks like this:

```
Find file: ~/code/study/~/code/study/
```

which you now can edit to

```
Find file: ~/code/study/~/other/code/study/
```

BTW: This is the only way I found if you want to modify the access to a remote dir:

```
Find file: /userA@remoteHost:/somedir
```

If you want to change userA to userB ivy doesn't allow editing that part at all.